# is `file_get_contents("php://input")` the only way to get post data from `fetch` and is it safe to use async- and hack-wise?

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, fetch

I'm trying to rewrite my JQuery `$.post()` code via native `fetch()` function. And it seems like the only way to do it with PHP server code is using `file_get_contents("php://input")`.
I do it like it is shown [here](https://www.mikestreety.co.uk/blog/how-to-use-fetch-in-javascript-to-get-or-post-data/) and [here](https://codepen.io/dericksozo/post/fetch-api-json-php):

js code:

```
fetch('/myscript.php', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: "same-origin",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify({par1:par1, par2:par2})
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(output => {
  // do stuff
});
```

myscript.php:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
// do stuff with $input['par1'], $input['par2']
echo $output;
```

There are two things which makes me worried:

1. The project has more than one fetch call like this. What if two fetch functions are called simultaneously with two different php script files? They both will access `php://input` at the same time. Won't it lead to a conflict?
2. With `$.post()` I was able to check if `myscript.php` hasn't been called directly by a hacker with this line of code:

   `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') die('Hack attempt!');`

   but with the new approach `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is undefined for some reason. Is there a way to ensure `myscript.php` is called with fetch or `php://input` ensures it automatically?
3. `fetch` is pretty modern function, but `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)` looks pretty weird and intended for some other use case. Isn't there a better way to fetch data from a php-based server?

Comment: define hacky and unintended

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, "weird and intended for some other use case"

Comment: The fact that you have to read the data from `php://input` has nothing to do directly with using `fetch`, but is the result of sending JSON as the request body. PHP only populates `$_POST`, if the post body is of either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` oder `multipart/form-data` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. Each script invocation has its own `php://input`.
2. How does that check if it's called by a hacker? Nothing stops a hacker from sending that header. But if you really want it, you can add the header yourself (which is what a hacker would do):

```
fetch('/myscript.php', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: "same-origin",
    headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify({par1:par1, par2:par2})
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(output => {
  // do stuff
});
```

3. You can send url-encoded parameters instead of JSON. Then PHP will parse them into `$_POST` as with normal forms.

```
fetch('/myscript.php', {
    method: 'post',
    mode: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: `par1=${encodeURIComponent(par1)}&par2=${encodeURIComponent(par2)}`
}).then(response => response.text())
.then(output => {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: is there some other way you could recommend to make hacker unable to call myscript.php or use it to an unintended way?

Comment: Not really. Anything the browser can do, so can a hacker by sending the same data.

Comment: No. Anything your website can do a hacker can do too.

Comment: Maybe use CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 3):

1. Each new process will get a separate "input", there is no risk of conflict.
2. You want CSRF tokens. Anyone can send a XMLHttpRequest
3. you are comparing oranges to apples. php://input is fine.

[php://input documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)